# Preserve unicode character while transoforming XML

Tags: java, xml, unicode, xml-parsing

I have an XML document. I read this document with Java's DocumentBuilder. Then I do some updates on DOM. And then I try to save this XML-representation with Transformer. And on the last step I get a problem.
Original XML document contains some unicode characters, for example `&#10;`. When I try to save this XML document with Java's Transformer, this character becomes simple line-break in the final file.

How can I preserve those unicode character when I am saving XML into file ?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Original XML document contains some unicode characters, for example `&#10;`.

The `&#...;` syntax is known as a numeric character reference. `&#10;` is not connected to Unicode (except in as much as all ASCII characters, including control code 10, are also Unicode characters).

> When I try to save this XML document with Java's Transformer, this character becomes simple line-break in the final file.

A line break and a `&#10;` character reference represent the same data in text content(*). The difference is already discarded when parsed by `DocumentBuilder` and will be for any parser conforming to the XML specification.

XML parsers do not, in general, retain information from the input document that is not present in the [infoset](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-infoset/), so parsing and serialising the same document without changes doesn't guarantee that the input and output will be the same. Differences include attribute order, spacing inside tags, which quotes are used around attribute values, and whether the text character `>` was written as `>`, `&gt;`, `&#62;`, `&#x3E;`, `&#x3e;`, or `&#x03E`, or...

The good news is there is almost never any reason to care. If the thing that's going to be reading your output is also an XML parser, it can't see any difference between a newline and a `&#10;` character reference either.

(*: this is not necessarily always true in atttibute value content though)

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The DOM has no knowledge of which characters were represented in the original source as literal characters and which were represented as character references, so it's impossible to "preserve" them - the information simply isn't there. A serializer will use character references for any characters that are impossible to represent in the output character encoding, but will generally use literal characters whenever it can.

The only time it'll use `&#10;` for a newline is inside attribute values, where literal newlines would be normalized to spaces the next time the file is parsed.

Answer (score 0):

Characters are not just 'lost'. What I assume (?) is that the unicode characters are 'deformed' reading or writing the stream.

Make sure you use correct encoding with streams (InputStreamReader, OutputStreamWriter) or when you display yourself the transformed result.

g.

Answer (score 0):

This library returns Stax2 XMLEvent with original texts, preserving unicode references as is.

https://github.com/irgaly/original-characters-stax-xml-parser

---

(edit)

further explanation:

You can use JDK's StAX Parser, XMLEventReader and XMLEvent.

XMLEvent has getLocation() that is a character offset of element's start position. Then you can get original string from the input XML String.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/stream/XMLEventReader.html
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/stream/events/XMLEvent.html#getLocation()

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30944534)

Comment: ok. I updated my post.